# Send messages to IBM MQ Uniform Cluster from stand alone queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

We're trying to send messages from a standalone Queue manager on 1 server) to Uniform IBM Cluster (UCL) with a set of Queue managers (QM1, QM2 and QM3). on 3 different servers

## ================================================================
Objects created and running on Uniform cluster with a set of Queue managers (QM1, QM2 and QM3):

Listener object 1415 on all 3 queue managers, listening on all 3 servers.
A receiver channel matching sender channel name created on QM1T created on all the queue managers QM1, QM2 and QM3 of the cluster UCL.
A local queue created to hold messages on all the queue managers QM1, QM2 and QM3 of the cluster UCL.

## ================================================================
Objects on our stand-alone queue manager. QM1T

Sender channel with CONNAME of all the 3 hosts of queue managers and their ports.
Transmission queue associated with Sender channel.

We'll need clarity on creation of QREMOTE, specifically how we could associate a QREMOTE with all the clustered Queue managers all at once ...is there a better way to do this and avoid single point of failures ? please let us know.

```
DEFINE QREMOTE('TEST.UCL') DEFPSIST(YES) CLUSTER('UCL') RQMNAME(???????????????) RNAME('UCL.TEST') XMITQ('QM1.TEST.XMIT')
```

While I can create QREMOTE definitions like below ?  now we have multiple remote queues that stand alone queue-manger needs to deal with and multiple Remote queue managers it needs to deal with...there can be single point of failure.

Specifically, I'm looking for is there something that does like RQMNAME(ANY QM)

```
DEFINE QREMOTE('TEST.UCL3') DEFPSIST(YES) CLUSTER('UCL') RQMNAME('QM3') RNAME('UCL.TEST') XMITQ('QM1.TEST.XMIT')
DEFINE QREMOTE('TEST.UCL2') DEFPSIST(YES) CLUSTER('UCL') RQMNAME('QM2') RNAME('UCL.TEST') XMITQ('QM1.TEST.XMIT')
DEFINE QREMOTE('TEST.UCL1') DEFPSIST(YES) CLUSTER('UCL') RQMNAME('QM1') RNAME('UCL.TEST') XMITQ('QM1.TEST.XMIT')
```

Comment: Your question suggests you are creating a SENDER channel with a comma-separated CONNAME pointing to three different queue managers. Do not do this. If you need to make connections to each of three different queue managers, make three different channels, or better yet put that stand-alone queue manager into a cluster with the three target queue managers.

Comment: @MoragHughson Can you explain why using CONNAME pointing to three different queue managers is not a good idea? The alias Qmanager setup  which is suggested by JoshMc did work for our use-case. With the approach that you suggested, can the messages be directed into a single remote queue with 3 different channels in play ?

Comment: Using a conname with three IP addresses that don't point to the same target qmgr can result in the channel being indoubt to a different partner and not being able to resolve that UoW because it is now connected to another one.

Comment: If you want to do this without a cluster you will need 3 channels and 3 QREMOTEs. Then you will need some logic in your code to decide which to use.  Better off just to use a cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to create an overlapping cluster that includes all four queue mangers, cluster UCL.TEST in the overlapping cluster on QM1, QM2 and QM3 then on QM1T define a QALIAS instead of a QREMOTE, this will allow the messages to be work load balanced across the three instances.

---

If you can only have a SDR channel from QM1T then below is another option that will work with your current channel setup with the restriction that messages will only flow initially to one of the three based on availability in the order you specify the CONNAME, but once it gets to the initial queue manger it will round robin across all of the available clusters queue instances.

First on QM1, QM2 and QM3 define the following queue manger alias to allow all three queue managers to accept messages and allow them to resolve to clustered queues:

```
DEFINE QREMOTE(UCL.QMA) RNAME('') RQMNAME('') XMITQ('')
```

Next on QM1, QM2 and QM3 cluster the QLOCAL and set CLWLUSEQ to ANY so that messages put to the clustered queue on any queue manger will round robin over all the instances:

```
ALTER QLOCAL(UCL.TEST) CLUSTER(UCL) CLWLUSEQ(ANY) DEFBIND(NOTFIXED)
```

Next on QM1T alter the QREMOTE like this:

```
DEFINE QREMOTE('TEST.UCL') DEFPSIST(YES) CLUSTER('') RQMNAME(UCL.QMA') RNAME('UCL.TEST') XMITQ('QM1.TEST.XMIT')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, we're able to accomplish our need using the Queue Manager Alias. However, we have a question on workload balancing ...while the MQPUTs are distributed across queue managers cluster queues, we have a problem with reads ...Reads are happening on one queue manager while others wait.

Comment: Uniform cluster should handle ensuring you have readers spread equally across the three member queue mangers,  you would need to run at least three instances of the reader for this to work,  best practice would be to run more than three so that you can self heal if one goes down.   Since the original question was not about readers,  you should open a new question with more details on the configuration, application setup, and problems faced with readers.   If my answer was helpful please feel free to also up vote it in addition to the accept you already gave.